# What is the difference between Blaze and SpaceBars in a Meteor application

Tags: meteor

I've been diving into Meteor and have heard referencing to Blaze, I know SpaceBars is Meteors Templating language. But where does Blaze come in? When I look at their GitHub page I just see templating which looks to me like SpaceBars.

Is Blaze to SpaceBars the same as DDP to WebSockets? I'm confused. Thanks.

Comment: See [this](https://www.meteor.com/blaze).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Blaze](https://www.meteor.com/blaze) is the engine responsible for rendering templates, while [Spacebars](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md) is a template language that defines templates. If you use Meteor you're stuck with Blaze (at least at the moment), but you can change the template language you use (at the moment, [Jade](https://atmospherejs.com/mquandalle/jade) is an alternative).

Comment: Is that a bad thing that I'm stuck with Blaze? I really don't mind it.

Comment: @Datsik, no it's not.

Answer (score 1):

While it's absolutely true what @Peppe L-G says, the links are a bit outdated. You can find info on [Blaze JS](http://blazejs.org) and [Spacebars](http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html) on the new open source info page of the [blaze project](https://github.com/meteor/blaze).